# File sent as email attachment via Excel VBA is always corrupt

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, outlook

I'm using the following error handling method to save a copy of the file that's currently open and send it to my email if it causes an error.

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath _
Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, _
ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub MainSub()
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim wb As Workbook
On Error GoTo NotifyandRepair
    Call Sub1
    Call Sub2
    Call Subn

Exit Sub
NotifyandRepair:
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.SaveAs TempPath & "ErroringFile.xlsx", FileFormat:= _xlNormal,AccessMode:=xlExclusive,ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.To = "name@company.com"
.Subject = "Error Occured - Error Number " & Err.Number
.Body = Err.Description
.Attachments.Add TempPath & "ErroringFile.xlsx"

.Send '~~> Change this to .Display for displaying the email
End With

Set OutApp = Nothing: Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub

Function TempPath() As String
TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

It appears to work fine. When an unhandled error occurs it sends me a copy of the file and its been renamed "ErroringFile.xlsx". The problem is the file is always corrupt.

Am I doing something wrong?

How do I fix this issue so the file isn't corrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the wrong FileFormat you SaveAs.

See [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017(v=office.14).aspx), you should be saving it as `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! According to that though, wouldn't `xlWorkbookNormal` also work for saving as an `.xlsx`? Or is the normal workbook type not `.xlsx`?

Comment: So it was a typo in the post. I think it's something different, since `xlWorkbookNormal` is not 51 (standard xlsx format). If you can open the email attachment in 7zip as archive, you may have more idea what that format supposed to be.

Comment: It wasn't a typo, I've seen both instances (`xlnormal` and `xlWorkbookNormal`), which only made things more confusing for me. I think your original suggestion, 'xlOpenXMLWorkbook` is the correct version. I'll try I tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: According to [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=y13kBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=what%27s+the+difference+between+xlWorkbookNormal+and+xlOpenXMLWorkbook&source=bl&ots=F1AAaYYPGp&sig=Bflk_brGTjnTB9zVrqjv1OdxN18&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi449z-zJ7LAhXBHB4KHZUtCZgQ6AEIKjAG) your answer is right.

Comment: Thanks, I tested with `xlNormal`, it opens fine if the file extension is **`.xls`**.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now as to why it would always be corrupt then if I'm tacking on the `.xlsx` when it's being set to the `.xls` format.